# Why was Perse a Nymph and not a Titan like both of her parents?

Tags: greek, titans, nymphs, circe

I've been reading "Circe" and it got me thinking: Circe's mother was a water nymph named Perse. Perse's parents were Oceanos and Tethys, who were both Titans. Why then is Perse a Nymph if both of her parents are Titans?
I have some possible ideas but it's all just speculation.

Some further info is that Perse was one of 3,000 siblings. If you want to read what they have about her on Wikipedia, here's the link.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perse_(mythology)

Comment: The short and simple answer is that Greek mythology is neither logical nor consistent, since it is not the creation of a single mind, but an accumulation of beliefs and practices of a diverse group of people.

Comment: I don't think you should look at the terms "Titan" and "Nymph" as if they denote species (if that's what you're doing). Nymphs are just minor nature deities. Not something different in kind from their forebears, but just different in power. I see it as more of a job description or role.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the nymphs were offspring of Titans; hence, not Titans proper.
The nymphs were born of Oceanus and Tethys.